# Are all Sass compilers the same?

Tags: sass, gulp

Is there a difference between different compilers, for example if I use node-sass or gulp-sass, and I've seen a few places with Postcss-nesting, postcss-variables and so on, is this the same thing? Is there a difference between them syntax-wise?

Answer (score 0):

There are no differences in sass syntax among the compilers.

There might be other differences for which you should read the documentation of specific compiler you use.

Answer (score 0):

`gulp-sass` is a Gulp plugin built with `node-sass`. You might want to check this answer for more information: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293161/pros-and-cons-of-node-sass-and-gulp-sass)